# Call custom exception whenever code reaches catch block

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, exception

This is my controller class in which I have made I am using `CUSTExceptionFilter` as an attribute over the controller.

```
[CustExceptionFilter]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration = 10)]
    public ActionResult OutPutTest()
    {
        try
        {
            int y = 5;
            int z = 0;
            int i = y / z;
        }
       // I want that whenever my code reached the catch block my CUSTException filter should be executed.
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error found in application:" + ex.Message);
        }
        ViewBag.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
        return View();

    }
}
```

I have a another Custom Exception Filter class in which i am writing the code regarding the exception to get the details from where the exception is coming

```
public class CustExceptionFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        MethodBase mb = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
        string methodName = mb.ReflectedType.Namespace + "." +                  mb.ReflectedType.Name + "." + mb.Name;
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.ExceptionMessage = "Custom Exception: Message from OnException method.";
    }
}
```

when I am executing it is not reaching the `CustExceptionFilter` class where I am getting the stack from where the exception is coming.

I want my code should call the `CUSTException` class every time whenever it reaches a catch block without me making any change in catch block.

Answer (score 1):

You are catching the exception in your catch block.

You have 2 ways

1. remove `try/catch` block

   ```
   public ActionResult OutPutTest()
   {
       int y = 5;
       int z = 0;
       int i = y / z;

       ViewBag.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
       return View();
   }
   ```
2. use `throw` in  catch block

   ```
   public ActionResult OutPutTest()
   {
       try
       {
           int y = 5;
           int z = 0;
           int i = y / z;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Error found in application:" + ex.Message);
           throw;
       }
       ViewBag.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
       return View();
   }
   ```

Comment: It is not working fully and by using throw it is reaching my CustException code when in the stack frame i am not getting the method name,controller name inside the CustException Code and it is not returning back to my controller after executing the CustExcetion Code to execute the View bag after the catch block.

Comment: That's not how exception filters working. I think you want to have a custom logging mechanism not exception filtering.